# How to write regex for Objective-C?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, regex, cocoa

I have some html data containing some img tags as follows:

```
img width=500 height=400
img width=400 height=250
img width=600 height=470
```

Height and width always changing. I have to replace that html data. I need to replace that html data to "img with=100" using Objective-C.

I wrote these but it's not matching

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/(img\\s)((width|height)(=)([0-9]+)"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:myhtmldata
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [myhtmldata length])];

NSString *modifiedString; 
if (numberOfMatches > 0)
{
   modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:myhtmldata
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [myhtmldata length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"img width=30"];

}
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Should you really be parsing HTML with regexes?

Comment: I need just change images size. isn't possible? This data comes to me as a string and I apply this data to a UIWebview.

Comment: @mturhan55: “I just need to…” is never a valid reason to parse HTML with regular expressions in a shipping application. Sadly, the WebKit DOM API isn't available on iOS; absent that, using JavaScript to manipulate the DOM is the lesser of two hacks.

Answer (score 2):

If I infer the intent correctly from your sample code, you just want to use `NSRegularExpression` to change the width to 30.  Then:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSError *regexError = nil;
        NSRegularExpressionOptions options = 0;
        NSString *sampleText = @"img width=500 height=400";
        NSString *pattern = @"^(img\\s+)width=\\d+(\\s+height=\\d+)";
        NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:options error:&regexError];

        sampleText = [expression stringByReplacingMatchesInString:sampleText
                                                          options:0
                                                            range:NSMakeRange(0,sampleText.length)
                                                     withTemplate:@"$1width=30$2"];
        printf("%s\n",[sampleText UTF8String]);
    }

}
```

prints `img width=30 height=400` to the console.

**EDIT:**

You change change the regular expression to `(img\s+width=)\d+\s+height=\d+` which when escaped properly will be:

```
@"(img\\s+width=)\\d+\\s+height=\\d+"
```

then change the template string to `@"$130"`.  IF you make those changes to the my original code, you should match all occurrences of the `img` tag embedded in HTML.  For example, it should change:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img width=500 height=400>
        <img width=520 height=100>
    </body>
</html>
```

to:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img width=30>
        <img width=30>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this what your specs call for?

Comment: Thank you for detailed reply. 

Firstly my html data are so big. There is not only that line @"img width=500 height=400".
Your code worked properly when i was executed but if sample text will be "some tags bla bla some tags img width=500 height=400 and more tags" replace don't work.

Comment: Secondly, i need replace "img width=500 height=400" to "img width=30". Height key and value must be delete.

Comment: I did. Your edited regex works great. Thank you so much and one more question. I googled a lot of time for objective-c and regex but I can't find good examples about this. Would you mind to give a good source for this ?

Comment: writing Perl code for years is a code start!  [This book](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1355137084&sr=8-1&keywords=regular+expressions) has been a big help.  The Apple documentation on `NSRegularExpression` isn't too bad either.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different method and it's working. Here is code :

```
NSArray* ary = [oldHtml componentsSeparatedByString:@"<img"];
NSString* newHtml = [ary objectAtIndex:0];
for (int i = 1; i < [ary count]; i++) {

    newHtml = [newHtml stringByAppendingString:[@"<img width=300 " stringByAppendingString:[[ary objectAtIndex:i] substringFromIndex:[[ary objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:@"src"].location]]];

}
```